# Got java.lang.NullPointerException while do getTemplate("report.ftl")

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, freemarker

I am using freemarker 2.3.23 in Eclipse to generate the report.
But got nullpointerException when trying to getTemplate. But the template file "report.ftl" is there. Not sure what I did wrong.
Below is the code:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_22);
try {
        cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("C:\\Users\\zzng"));
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        cfg=null;
        return false;
}
cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
rptTemplate=cfg.getTemplate("report.ftl");
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.barclaycardus.cd.freemarker.Reports.getTemplate(Reports.java:63)
>     at UnitTest.Test.testConfiguration(Test.java:11)    at
>   UnitTest.Test.main(Test.java:20)

Comment: So, what is line 63 of Reports.java?

Comment: so cfg is null then. you should be able to step through on debug to verify this. I'm assuming the issue is occurs in the try block

Comment: @JBNizet It's the last row in above code snippet:rptTemplate=cfg.getTemplate("report.ftl");

Comment: @peggy You are right the cfg is null. I found the reason cfg was declared twice, which causes the problem. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: no problem. In general, if you are getting a null pointer exception, your first move should be to go to the line the exception is thrown and look at the object that is being acted upon (cfg in this case). This will take care of the vast majority of null pointer exceptions you can encounter

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but looks like you sorely need double quotes around that file name. Try: cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("C:\\Users\\zzng"));

Comment: @peggy Good advice, will do that in the future.Thanks.

Comment: @unigeek that was removed accidentally, just added back. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet above works. 
The reason it didn't work for me was because I put them into two separate method and declared twice, which caused cfg to be different variable.